# Is there a predefined method to padarray in java by a given no of rows and columns with a number

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to padarray in java that is add row and column to a existing array in front and back with a given number.

For example :-

```
let x =  1  2  3
         4  5  6
         7  8  9
```

and now want to 2 rows and columns of zeros in this:

```
   x =  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 2 3 0 0
        0 0 4 5 6 0 0
        0 0 7 8 9 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, i want to know that is there a existing method or way to do this in java like it is available in matlab using the predefined method called `padarray(x,[r,c])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never add rows or columns to 2 dimensional arrays at all. Arrays are fixed size. You could use a dynamic data structure such as `List<List<Integer>>`.

What you also can do is create a new array (that is bigger or smaller than your current one) using the [`Arrays.copyOf(int[] original, int newLength);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) method.

You array `x` is like:

```
  int[][] x = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
```

There is no one-liner (I know of) to *transform* it to your desired format. You have to create a method that creates a new 2 dimensional array and place your values at the correct indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code that takes the 2D array you want padded, what you want it to be padded with, and how many pads to surround the array with (yours would be 2 because you want your array surrounded with 2 layers of 0's).

```
public static int[][] padArray(int[][] arr, int padWith, int numOfPads) {
    int[][] temp = new int[arr.length + numOfPads*2][arr[0].length + numOfPads*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < temp[i].length; j++) {
            temp[i][j] = padWith;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            temp[i+numOfPads][j+numOfPads] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```